# How to properly seed a 64 bit random generator with time

Tags: c++, c++11, random, random-seed

I would like to generate 64 bit integers using the standard `c++` `std::mt19937_64` without manually seeding it. When defining the seed though, this question occurred to me: is there a proper way of seeding such a random generator using the current time (eg. producing a number based on the current time point, that is at least as big as a 64 bit `int`)? Something like counting milliseconds from the Unix epoch? Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: `time_t` is 64-bits when it's supported. Not that current Epoch Time needs more than 32-bits to be represented, so if you are seeding it with time it makes no difference.

Comment: See also: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/109260/seed-stdmt19937-from-stdrandom-device

Comment: You can do things like:
auto duration = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration{ std::chrono::high_resolution_clock().now().time_since_epoch() };
auto nanosec = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(duration).count();
auto seed = static_cast<std::mt19937_64::result_type>(nanosec);
auto engine = std::mt19937_64{ seed };